# Camera Clipping

Tags: camera

I've adjusted my camera clipping to be a wide as it can be, but the thing seems to cause the problem is the "clip start" and not "clip end". I've adjusted to be 0.000001 but it still clip my scene in camera view mode. Any way to help this?[image]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the camera clip setting only affects the render. Does it help if you change the 'Clip Start' value under the 'view' menu there? Currently it's set to 1m

Comment: You're using an Orthographic Camera. Try to place it further away from your objects. Shortcuts G > Z > Z (for local axis) then move your mouse towards your body

Answer (score 0):

Zoom out, or set camera properties for a wider angle "lens". Looks like you're at 36mm and wider angle means lower value.